# Ninject 3.0 with Mono exception

Tags: .net, linux, mono, ninject

I'm trying to get a .net application running in mono that references Ninject. I've downloaded the mono ninject build from here:

https://code.google.com/p/ninject2/downloads/detail?name=Ninject-3.0.1.10-release-mono-4.0.zip&can=2&q=

and copied the dll to the bin folder of my app. But when I run the app I get the following exception:

Missing method Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax::To<[1]>() in assembly /data/sportingcharts/SCTrunk/DataLoader/bin/Debug/Ninject.dll, referenced in assembly '...'

I've tried a number of the mono builds and they all result in the same error. The function that does the bindings in my application looks like this:

```
private void DefaultDALBind<Interface, Implementation>(string connectionString) where Implementation:Interface
{
    Bind<Interface>().To<Implementation>().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
}
```

I've also tried downloading the latest source for inject from GIT but the Ninject.build nant script fails with:

```
Function call failed. Expression: ${PInvoke::IsWow64Process()}
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    IsWow64Process
```

Anyone one know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.2 (tarball Fri Apr  5 21:05:52 UTC 2013)

Comment: This is a beta and Ninject hasn't been tested against this version. We see no issue with the current stable 2.0.10. You probably ran into a bug of the latest mono beta. I remember mono having had problems with generic in early 2.0.x versions too.

Comment: Regarding your nant build problem. I guess you try to build on linux. The build process is just for Windows. To build on Linus you have to adjust is. E.g. replace that PInvoke with true or false depending on your system

Comment: installed 'Mono JIT compiler version 2.11.4 ' getting the same error